# Looking for a PDF -> PNG converter that can keep transparency

Tags: pdf, image-conversion, png

Problem:

I have a default OSX cursor file, that I want to modify and save as PNG to later load in my program.

Current solution:

I found an online PDF -> PNG converter, which did the job, however turns out this converter didn't keep the transparency in the resulting PDF and used white color where the alpha channel should be.

So, now I need to have the file converted and keep the alpha channel.

Is there something online or some kind of software that can do that?

Comment: What platform? Can you post the pdf somewhere so we can test it?

Comment: @Tetsujin, I don't care about platform.

Comment: Are you looking for a free solution or a commercial product?

Comment: how is a converter to know to keep the 'alpha' as pdf don't contain alpha (to my knowledge)

Comment: @depperm - that's why I want to see the file. See what it comprises; a PDF is really just a container.

Comment: @BenThompson, free.

Comment: @Tetsujin, the pdf contains an image of the cursor that can be used. It is one page pdf that have the image. If you have an Apple you can find those at `/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HiServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors`

Comment: Photoshop & GraphicCOnverter can do it, Preview & Gimp can't [on a very quick look, I don't use Gimp enough to know how it really works]

Comment: I just opened one of the cursor.pdf files in Preview, converted to PNG, and the white background remained white. Acrobat did the same. Why do you think it should be transparent?

Comment: @depperm, PDF definitely has some very sophisticated notions of "alpha" ([Adobe: 20 years of transparency in PDF](https://blog.adobe.com/en/publish/2022/01/31/20-years-of-transparency-in-pdf)), but in general, I think OP sees the white background as disposable as they're very focused on extracting the "foreground" elements.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick can probably do everything you need.

I'll start by copying one of the cursor PDFs to my Desktop:

```
cp \
 /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors/busybutclickable/cursor.pdf \
 ~/Desktop/cursor.pdf
```

ImageMagick's **convert** tool alone can convert a PDF to PNG, and will also remove the white background:

```
convert cursor.pdf cursor.png
```

and I get:

[image: cursor.pdf straight conversion to P-N-G file]

If you need a higher-resolution conversion, drop-in the `-density ###` option:

```
convert -density 300 cursor.pdf cursor.png
```

Once you have a basic conversion that you're happy with, you can then make the convert command slice up the image for you.

Using the default conversion, I get a 28x600 px image, and there are 15 individual images, which is 28x40 px per image, so I tell the convert command that I want it to slice the image into a series of images that are 28x40 px:

```
convert cursor.pdf -crop 28x40 +repage +adjoin cursor-%02d.png
```

and now I have 15 individual PNGs, with transparent backgrounds:

```
ls cursor-*.png
cursor-00.png   cursor-03.png   cursor-06.png   cursor-09.png   cursor-12.png
cursor-01.png   cursor-04.png   cursor-07.png   cursor-10.png   cursor-13.png
cursor-02.png   cursor-05.png   cursor-08.png   cursor-11.png   cursor-14.png
```

(`%02d` is syntax from the `printf` command which means "print a digit, padded 2 places with a ``0'' (zero)".  This is just nice for sorting/displaying numbers, like in the `ls` command above.)

For macOS, ImageMagick recommends installing through **brew**:

- https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx

and I found those *spells* above (ImageMagick slang for commands and options/paramaters) from these StackOverflow posts:

- [How to replace white background color with transparent of an image in ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424018/how-to-replace-white-background-color-with-transparent-of-an-image-in-imagemagic)
- [Convert PDF to PNG using ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869908/convert-pdf-to-png-using-imagemagick)
- [Using imagemagick how can i slice up an image into several separate images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636350/using-imagemagick-how-can-i-slice-up-an-image-into-several-separate-images)